# PostgreSQL/JDBC - How do I prepare-call a function with parameter CITEXT (TEXT)?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I created a table with a `CITEXT` column, `CITEXT` (case-insensitive version of `TEXT`) being an extension I previously loaded using `CREATE EXTENSION citext;`

```
CREATE TABLE artists (
    artist_id   SERIAL   PRIMARY KEY,
    artist      CITEXT   UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_artist(_artist CITEXT) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        _artist_id INT;
    BEGIN
        SELECT artist_id INTO _artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist = _artist;

        IF (_artist_id IS NULL) THEN
            INSERT INTO artists (artist) VALUES (
                _artist
            ) RETURNING artist_id INTO _artist_id;
        END IF;

        RETURN _artist_id;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now I am trying to call the function in java using

```
public int addArtist(String name) throws SQLException {
    int artist_id;

    try (CallableStatement callableStatement = 
            connection.prepareCall("{ ? = CALL add_artist(?) }")) {
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        callableStatement.setString(2, name);
        callableStatement.execute();
        artist_id = callableStatement.getInt(1);
    }

    return (artist_id != 0) ? artist_id : -1;
}
```

The same method in calling functions works fine if the argument passed to the sql function is type of `INTEGER` or `VARCHAR(n)`.

I assume `callableStatement.setString(2, name);` is throwing the `SQLException` because `setString()` is to be be used for VARCHAR(n) fields?

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function add_artist(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:465)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:458)
at postgresql.PostgreSQL.addArtist(PostgreSQL.java:61)
at postgresql.PostgreSQLConnector.main(PostgreSQLConnector.java:26)
```

`CallableStatement` has no methods like `setText(int i, String text)` - What must I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. All I had to do was casting the parameter to `CITEXT` using `::citext`.

```
public int addArtist(String name) throws SQLException {
    int artist_id;

    try (CallableStatement callableStatement = 
            connection.prepareCall("{ ? = CALL add_artist(?::citext) }")) {
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        callableStatement.setString(2, name);
        callableStatement.execute();
        artist_id = callableStatement.getInt(1);
    }

    return (artist_id != 0) ? artist_id : -1;
}
```

Comment: The other option is to set `stringtype=unspecified` as a connection parameter.

Comment: Interesting, is that more common than casting? And are there differences between setting `stringtype=unspecified` and casting the argument within the `prepareCall()` string?

Comment: Casting is preferable if you're able to. If you're using some ORM that doesn't give you that level of control, passing `stringtype=unspecified` asks PgJDBC to treat strings like untyped literals and let the database server infer their data type.

Comment: Thank you for the information, then I'll go with casting. Nevertheless, tempting to use the `stringtype` parameter out of lazyness.